# Module vs. component design

Tags: module, components

What is the difference between module vs. component design?

Comment: This depends on the language/environment you are talking about (e.g. a .Net module is something completely different than a perl module). Which are you interested in?

Comment: The only context i can think of that would make sense for this question is Joomla!, but til we get some clarification, i'm not gonna bother answering.

Comment: in terms of frameworks. Can you give me example of PHP framework that is module vs. component?

Comment: I'm also struggling with that separation. I'm thinking of it in terms of synthesis/analysis. Components are _put together_ (synthesis) to build a software. Modules are the result of _dividing_ (analysis) the code. So components are about the high-level design of a software, whereas modules are more about organization on the code level.

Answer (score 28):

I'd like to share my idea about this difference.

Both component and module are used to refer to a group of functions or a part of a function. Module is more logical, for example: module Finance, module HR, module Manufacturing... in ERP system. On the other hand, component is more physical. In software, it can be a dll, ocx, exe,...

There is no criteria to measure which one is greater than the other. One component can contain list of modules, and one module also can contain many components. Components are used to model a system in technical view, and module is used to model the system in function view ( functionalities of the system)

Comment: This is definitely a wrong answer. Quoting from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815065: "The use of DLLs helps promote modularization of code, code reuse, [...]" - you cannot say "component is more physical", DLLs are all about modularity and you cannot get more physical than that.

Comment: Same for OSGI bundles https://www.osgi.org/developer/architecture/: "Therefore, modularity is at the core of the OSGi specifications and embodied in the bundleconcept. In Java terms, a bundle is a plain old JAR file" - again modules are physical.

Comment: I agree to @Tin, the use of the term "physical" may be debatable but in general Tin's answer is much clearer.

Answer (score 15):

Components and modules are too often confused with each other.  They
are, however, not the same, and the implications of one, does not
necessarily hold for the other.

Modularity is the partitioning of code into modules of related
functionality.  In many programming languages, a module is simply a
source file.  It is common practice that if the source file grows too
big, you can split it into two or more source files, and put these
into a new directory; while a directory is often not called a module,
this kind of decomposition is still modular.

A component, on the other hand, can be composed in different ways with
other components to form different programs.  That is, there is a
separate composition stage, where real people decide which components
should be used together.

I have seen component design being used to enforce some notion of hard
modularity.  This approach cannot be recommended because of the rather
significant overhead of composition: the composition complexity grows
polynomial with the number of components.  And the number of
components grows linearly with the number of functionality groups,
because once you get started with modularity by component
decomposition, you force yourself to create a new component whenever
you would otherwise just need a new module, because that new module
would otherwise not really belong anywhere.  At a 100 components, the
composition overhead became a full-time job, and each composition
iteration would take up to a couple of weeks, despite numerous
automation efforts.  This significantly impeded development.

My simplest recommendation is to stay away from components if at all
possible; well-knowing that components may sometimes be a necessity.
For instance if multiple independent organizations are involved in a
project, one component for each organization seem acceptable.

It is a matter of taste, how fine grained your decomposition into
modules should be, though everyone agrees that modularity is a good
thing.

If I know the name of a function, my editor will find it soon enough.
On the other hand, if for some reason I don't know the name of a
function (or a class for that matter), modularity becomes more
important.

I would expect the later case, to only be an issue for functionality that
you can experience from using the program, so try to make the
decomposition of your program into modules reflect an intuitive
decomposition of the behaviour of your program into areas of
functionality.

Answer (score 14):

There is a reference in [the «OSGi in Action» book](https://www.manning.com/books/osgi-in-action), which, I believe, explains the differences well.

> ## Modules vs. components
>
> Doesn't it sound like modules and components have a lot in common? They both provide stuff to each other and consume stuff from each other. They're also packaged as independent deployment units. Couldn't these two be considered one and the same or at least be combined? Yes, they could, but components and modules serve different purposes and are somewhat orthogonal (they're not completely orthogonal, because  components are made from code that can ultimately be packaged into modules).
>
> Modules deal with code packaging and the dependencies among code. Components deal with implementing higher-level functionality and the dependencies among components. Components need their code dependencies managed, but they technically don't need a module system to do it (often it's us programmers doing it via the class path).
>
> A good summary is that you can think of modules as dealing with static code and compile-time dependencies, whereas components deal with instances and execution-time dependencies.
>
> — «11.1.1 What are components?», «OSGi in Action» (page 347).

Comment: Agree; I just want to reinforce this view. The key to understanding the difference between modules and components is in how we view the system: a static view where the modules and the dependencies between them are derived directly from the code and an instance view where the components and the dependencies/links between them are result of runtime processing and/or a separate pre-execution configuration step.

Comment: I agree with you @arpadf

Answer (score 6):

If you mean module in the sense of modularity there is a definition in the IEEE Standard Glossary of Software Engineering Terminology:

> "Modularity is the degree to which a system or computer program is composed of discrete components such that a change to one component has minimal impact on other components."

And [Dr. Bertrand Meyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Meyer) stated five criteria for modularity:

- Decomposability of the problem into sub-problems
- Composability of modules to produce new systems
- Understandability of a module in isolation
- Continuity - small changes have localized effects
- Protection - fault isolation

Comment: If you're going to quote an official source, it would be preferable to get the quote right: `The degree to which a system or computer program is composed of discrete components such that a change to one component has minimal impact on other components`

Answer (score 5):

For digital development and UI consideration (HTML/CSS/JS), I use this approach to ensure I'm staying organized and thinking before doing. Has proven to create cleaner, more organized code which translates nicely to doing more with less.

In a typical stylesheet, I'm currently setting up like this:

```
/* Style Guide – Mobile First
   1. =Setup
   2. =Modules as independent units made up of components
   3. =Components as group of reusable code containing more than one element
   4. =Classes
   5. =Responsive as enhancement
*/
```

- Modules as independent units made up of components: Header, Footer, Sections, Articles, Aside, etc. A house is made up of many rooms, all with special styles and functions to create an independent whole.
- Components as a group of reusable code containing more than one element: Unordered Lists, Quotes, Cards, Tables, etc.

I wrote a fuller explanation you can read [here](https://tmblr.co/Z_o-Hx27VJp4g).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Component is a runtime entity (can be made up of modules), independent runnable unit

Module is a partitioned system into implementation units, independent task assignment. Modules might or might not be a component

Answer (score 1):

In my view, `Module` and `Component` are all just a couple of functions and assets.

And the different between them is:

**Component has business logical and module not.**

For example,this text input area is just a Module, but when there was some post api called,it become a Component. you can put a module everywhere and it will work fine, but Componet just can be used in a specific page or view(coz it has a specific api call)

Comment: I like the assertion that a component contains business logic and a module doesn't

Comment: Me too @ESR, that's a point.